# order of debugging - inline breakpoints with await keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, async-await

When I debug in vs code, the order of execution of the inline breakpoints is not always the same for async functions.

For instance :

```
const user = **break 1 **await User.**break 2 **findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
const token = **break 4 **await user.**break 3 **generateAuthToken()
```

Why does it sometimes debug "await" before the function, and sometimes not ?

Inside "findByCredentials", there's another line where the "await" breakpoint runs ***before*** the function :

```
const user = **break 1**await User.**break 2 **findOne({ email })
```

Inside "generateAuthToken", there's another line where the "await" breakpoint runs ***after*** the function :

```
**break 2**await user.**break 1**save()
```

Comment: isn't it simply because they are asynchronous, and run in parallel process?

Comment: @MisterJojo No, the four points in that code are sequential. Or are you saying that the surrounding function might be called multiple times (i.e. with different `req`uests)?

Comment: Are you sure that "break 1" is an inline breakpoint and not a whole-line breakpoint?

Comment: @Bergi , yes. Same behavior if I explicitly set inline breakpoints using shift-f9 before and after "await".

Comment: Oh! Look! There's a pattern : "User" is the model class (capital "U"), on which I call a static method, while "user" is the model instance, on which I call an instance method.